# Problemas con mensaje TempData

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy llamando a un método que según el resultado final muestra un mensaje u otro mediante tempdata

```
var departamentos = Repositorios.RepositorioPersonal.getDepartamentos();
if (departamentos.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (var grabar in departamentos)
      {
         Departamento dept = new Departamento();
         dept.Descripcion = grabar.Name;
         dept.IdDepartamentoNuo = grabar.Id;
         db.Departamento.Add(dept);
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
      TempData["MsgType"] = "success";
      TempData["Msg"] = "Departamentos actualizados.";
}
else
{
  TempData["MsgType"] = "success";
  TempData["Msg"] = "No hay departamentos nuevos.";
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Pero los mensajes no los muestra. En otros metodos tengo esto mismo y si funciona perfectamente, no se si hay algo mal que no veo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo estaba bien, el problema es que al llamar por ajax al ActionResult no se actualizaba la pagina y no cogía los TempData.

Lo que he hecho es en vez de pasar TempData he guardado los mensajes en variables y los he pasado por JSON